# TKInter - The text in the label changes window's width

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm building a calculator in python, using the tkinter toolkit. The problem is that when the text is typed in the calculator (and added to the label that shoes the calculation) the whole width of the window changes and becomes longer. What can I do in order to solve it?

Here is some important parts of the code: (the main class inherits from tk.Frame)

```
labelStyle = {"padx":10, "pady":10, "justify":"left"}
calculationsLabel = tk.Label(self, text="", **labelStyle)
calculationsLabel.grid(row=0, column=1, **gridStyle)
self.master.resizable(0,0)
self.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
self.calculationsLabel=calculationsLabel

for number in range(9,0,-1):
        ...
        tk.Button(self, ...).grid(...)
```

The images that illustrates the problem:

[image: the calculator without text]
[image: the calculator with text]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a couple of things to prevent the label from changing the window size:

1. Give the label a width of 1 (one). By *not* giving the label a width you are implicitly saying "grow bigger when the text is bigger". By giving it an explicit width you are saying "no matter how big the text is, don't grow if the text is bigger".
2. use the `columnspan` option to grid, to get the cell that the label is in to span the width of your grid of buttons. Use the sticky option, so that even though the label requests only one character of width, grid will force it to grow wide enough to fit the space.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Just one more thing: How can I show the last typed numbers? When the user types a long expression the focus is not on the last number, but the first one. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `columnspan` argument to let the label stretch over top all of your columns, instead of stretching out the first one. Add to your grid method:

```
calculationsLabel.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=7 **gridStyle)
```

(replacing 7 with however many columns you actually have)

Comment: Thank you very very much! it works. But the width still changes when the text is longer than the window's width.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `columnspan` option of `grid` to make the label span the complete width of the calculator.
Then, if you want the number to be on the left use `anchor=W` in the `Label`.

This way the window only expands when the `Label` is longer than the complete window. And you can even prevent that by using the `Label`'s `width` option.

Comment: Thank you very very much! it works. But the width still changes when the text is longer than the window's width.

Comment: Add `width=x` to your `labelStyle` to force it to a width of x characters. Try out what value of x fits your calculator.